# Google Developer Console API Project page "Failed to load"

Tags: console, google-api, google-api-client

For a few hours now I've been having trouble getting onto my API Project's pages to access my API information and enable/disable some API's.

The problem is, the pages are loading incredibly slow and eventually spew out:
"Failed to load", thus not allowing me to access the API pages.

Here's an image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vEvw.jpg

EDIT: A few other people I've asked are having the same problem. 
Does anyone know exactly what's going on?

Comment: Same for me. Unable to use the Google Developers Console currently!

Comment: I think they are updating something.  I just got a popup saying you have to reaccept terms of use.

Comment: It's still like this for me, did it resolve itself for you?

Comment: Are you still seeing this issue? Did you try disabling any browser extensions that you have installed in case they are causing problems?